# Most suitable way to do client side validations in a rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What is the best way to do client side validations in rails:

- Client side validations gem?
- Jquery validations plugin?

Provided that i am bounded with not adding model validations

Comment: Define "best". Validation of what?

Comment: just use one of npm/jquery plugins, not a gem

Comment: @jvillian  "best"  here i guess suitable

Comment: Which 'client side validations gems' are you considering?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your ruby project. If its required fomrs and you are using a gem like simple_form to generate your forms. You should use

[Rails Client Side Validations](https://github.com/DavyJonesLocker/client_side_validations)

It supports simple_form_for as well as form_for helpers.

For further use of jQuery Validation plugin take a look at [jQuery Validation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/)